# How to wait 24hrs before completing an async task?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, delay

I'm making an MVC app with the .NET Framework and in one of my controllers I call an async task that sends an e-mail to the signed in user.

This task is called upon when the user clicks a specific checkbox and the e-mail is meant to work as sort of reminder.

The entire task works as intended (the user gets an e-mail when the checkbox is checked), but I need it to wait 24 hours before actually sending the e-mail, as it is a reminder.

Currently the e-mail is sent right away, how can I delay the completion of my "e-mail task", while the code continues?

Comment: [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) to the resque!

Comment: You could store the email and then run a separate job (every few minutes) to check for emails to send

Comment: ^^ That.  Don't start a 24 hour wait and then send an email.  Imagine you have 500 of them queued up and the server is restarted because Windows.  They'd all be lost.

Comment: As @phuzi mentions, you should place it into some form of storage, such as a table in your database, or a file on disk, and then regularly check if that queue contains stuff to send. If you keep it in memory, and your instance recycles (deployment, high memory usage, long lifetime), you will lose that email.

Comment: The application (and the mailtask) isn't going to be used daily, maybe once or twice week. I imagine the maximum e-mails in the queue is two. Is a simple delay then possible? Or would you still store away the e-mails?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a library like [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) which lets you schedule background jobs and backs them with persistent storage.

You can then easily schedule a job like:

```
BackgroundJob.Schedule(
    () => SendEmail("user@domain"),
    TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic [X Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). While it may be possible to make your system wait 24 hours you are creating a very fragile system that can be affected by app pool resets and server reboots.

Putting aside the possibility of an unexpected reboot, what happens when your maintenance cycle comes around and a scheduled reboot is going to happen? How many queued email reminders will you have that you can't do anything with?

The best approach for systems that don't immediately use their data is to buffer it through some form of storage scheme. It could be as simple as writing queued emails to files on the system, or something more robust like a database with a dedicated email sending service.

I have used a LOT of email sending systems over the years, and even for immediate sends we have used a database intermediary, with one dedicated email sending Windows service to produce and send the actual email. By centralizing the email production you not only get one place to maintain your email sending code, but you can also increase the durability of the whole system.

Bonus points if your database is part of a high availability cluster, as in this kind of system the database becomes the critical point. If it is then you're protected from any form of downtime other than a total network outage.

Answer (score -1):

Let the Task wait for 24 hours before sending the mail.

```
     await Task.delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
```

Add this line in your async function bfore sending the email

Comment: Alternatively, `Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromDays(1))` or `Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(24))` can be used

Comment: Actually, using `Task.Delay` is fragile in this scenario. Suppose your application crashed (or killed) and all your  reminders will be lost.

Comment: @hal +1 if he is running in IIS the max timeout of a request wont be able to be set high enough for this to succeed. Not to mention application pool resets.